# encoding of filenames in zip archives

Tags: zip, archive-utility

When I unpack a zip archive (with standard 'archive utility') that was created under windows, cyrillic characters in filenames become some gibberish.

Just the filenames are the problem, actual contents of files is ok.

How to fix this?

(Yosemite, if that's important. In general, I have a lot of files with cyrillic filenames — and they are displayed just fine (including on flash drives from windows users etc).)

**Upd.** Looks like the source of the problem (many modern zip unarchivers assume that filenames are in unicode, but that's not always the case) and a possible **workaround** (`convmv`) is described e.g. at http://blogs.gnome.org/happyaron/2010/09/03/workaround-of-file-name-problem-while-unzip-handling-cjk-encodings/

Comment: Do you have that font in your font book?

Comment: What Mac and what OS X are you using?

Comment: Thanks, to clarify, just the file name or also the content become gibberish? file names read by Finder, while the content is read by associated application.

Comment: Just the filenames, actual contents of files is ok

Comment: Thanks, so it is your Finder (system fonts) having the problem.

Comment: I just tried Москва as file name on my Mavericks and it worked fine. So can you type (rename) file names in Cyrillic.

Comment: @Buscar웃 No offence meant, but have you actually read the question? The problem is with the way unarchiver interprets encoding of filenames in zip files. Yes, cyrillic filenames in general work fine — and in principle I can rename a couple hundred files by hand.

Comment: No offense taken, just trying to clarify since your original question lacks some details.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Qt based utility specifically for handling and fixing double encoded filenames: 
https://github.com/dennis97519/EncodingConverter

Answer (score 0):

I found this that might help you.

> Assuming your decompress tool passes the raw filenames directly to the
>   VFS layer, it's not enough for the filenames to be in UTF-8. They must
>   also be in Normal Form D. Having the filenames in [Normal Form C](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1173/_index.html)
>   will end up having them mangled in the VFS layer.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution is to use [The Unarchiver](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-unarchiver/id425424353?mt=12) (free on App Store) which, by default, is configured to automatically detect the filename encoding. If it does not detect the language, you can launch the program and under **Preferences** select the "Advanced" tab and configure the "Filename encoding" manually.